# CSS flyout menu issue

Tags: css

I have for like 2 hours tried to find out the problem with the fly-out menu on the home page of [this link](http://simco2.siteprogression.com/)

When you hover over our capabilities link on the page it it fly's out properly but the main background won't stretch to accommodate the width I gave it while the hover does. The code are as shown below

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
         <li><a href="index.php" class="current">Home </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Capabilities </a>
           <ul class="innerul">
             <li><a href="quilt.html">Wire Harness & Cable Assemblies</a></li>
             <li><a href="quilting-services.html">Electro Mechanical Assemblies</a></li>
             <li><a  href="bags-&amp;-totes.html">On-Site Machine Shop</a></li>
             <li><a href="zombie-felties.html">FAcilities & Equipment listing</a></li>
             <li><a href="coming-soon.html"> Quality Assurance</a></li>
             <li><a href="coming-soon.html"> Computer Control System</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="process-control.php">Process Control</a></li>
         <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
       </ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu
{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px 0 0 0;
        list-style: none;

}

#menu li
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 192px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}



#menu a
{
        float: left;
        height: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 192px;
        color: #999;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
        text-decoration: none;

}

#menu .innerul li li:hover > a
{
    color: #fafafa;
    width: 250px;
}

*html #menu li a:hover /* IE6 */
{
        color: #fafafa;
}

#menu li:hover > ul
{
    width: 250px;
        display: block;


}

/* Sub-menu */

#menu li .innerul
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #192833;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1f323f, #192833);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #192833));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1f323f, #192833);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#1f323f, #192833);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1f323f, #192833);
    background: linear-gradient(#1f323f, #192833);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}



#menu li .innerul li
{
    float: none;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #010101, 0 2px 0 #2b4253;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #010101, 0 2px 0 #2b4253;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #010101, 0 2px 0 #2b4253;
}

#menu li .innerul li:last-child
{
    width: 250px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#menu li .innerul li a
{
    width: 250px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
        height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
        text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a /* IE6 */
{
        height: 10px;
        width: 192px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a /* IE7 */
{
        height: 10px;
        width: 192px;
}

#menu li .innerul li a:hover
{
    background: #0186ba;
     width: 250px;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
        background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}

#menu li .innerul li:first-child a
{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    width: 250px;
}

#menu li .innerul li:first-child a:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
     width: 250px;
    left: 30px;
    top: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #1f323f;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after
{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec;

}

#menu ul li:last-child a
{
     width: 192px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after
{
     width: 192px;
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
}

* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
 #left {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#rack #header #navbar #menu li .innerul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It must be due to some other UL css .... everything is fine in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/H4SzB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top menu CSS rule is more specific than the inner one. Change `#rack #header #navbar ul` to `#rack #header #navbar > ul` to make sure this rule gets only applied to the top menu.

Also increase your 250px width to 350px to make sure you have enough room for the text.

Comment: This is not a complete fix but it should get started. Make sure you apply a similar change where necessary.